# for loop printing out last item in my array only

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want my for loop to print out every item in the array, not just the last item. Cant figure out where I'm going wrong:

```
var patients = ["Julia", "Kelly", "Thomas", "Clare"];

function lineOfPatients(line) {
 if (!line.length) {
     return "Empty"
 }
 for(var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
     var list = `${i + 1}. ${line[i]},`
 }
  return `The line is currently: ${list}`
}

 lineOfPatients(patients)
```

This returns "The line is currently: 4. Clare,"

I want it to return "The line is currently: 1. Julia, 2. Kelly, 3. Thomas, 4. Clare"

Comment: Initialize `list` to `""` and then use `list += ...` not `list = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `join` method on `lines` array which will contain your lines.

```js
var patients = ["Julia", "Kelly", "Thomas", "Clare"];

function lineOfPatients(line) {
    if (!line.length) {
        return "Empty";
    }

    var lines = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        var list = `${i + 1}. ${line[i]}`
        lines.push(list)
    }

    return `The line is currently: ${lines.join(", ")}`
}

console.log(lineOfPatients(patients))
```

Comment: This is the best solution, IMO

Comment: @mhodges, Thanks mate!

Comment: Best of both worlds, nice.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are reassigning the `list` variable each time through the loop, so you are overwriting the previous value.

To avoid this, use the `+=` operator instead of the `=` operator like so:

```js
var patients = ["Julia", "Kelly", "Thomas", "Clare"];

function lineOfPatients(line) {
 if (!line.length) {
     return "Empty"
 }
 var list = "";
 for(var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
     list += `${i + 1}. ${line[i]}, `
 }
  return `The line is currently: ${list}`
}

console.log(lineOfPatients(patients))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that with each iteration of your for-loop, you redeclare `` var list = `${i + 1}. ${line[i]},` `` so that by the time you return, `list` only equals the last element in the array.

You could do this:

```
function lineOfPatients(line) {
  if (!line.length) {
    return "Empty"
  }
  var returnString = "The line is currently: "
  for(let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    let patient = ` ${i + 1}. ${line[i]},`;
    returnString += patient;
  }
  return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want. (Got carried away with code golf)

```
const patients = ["Julia", "Kelly", "Thomas", "Clare"]

const lineOfPatients = (line) => "The line is currently: " + (!line || !line.length) ? "Empty" : line.map((patient, idx) => `${idx + 1}. ${patient}`).join(', ')

console.log(lineOfPatients(patients))
```

The reason it's not working is because your redeclaring the variable `list`on every loop. Even if you moved it out of the loop, your not appending the output from the for-loop, your assigning it. It will always be the output from the last loop.

Answer (score 0):

`var list` is being declared inside your loop. This means that it is being recreated with a new value on each itteration. Declare this variable outside of the loop, as an array. E.g,

```
var list = new Array();
```

Then, in your loop, add to the array;

```
list[i] = .....
```

Comment: string concatenation will suffice here

Comment: True. I guess it depends on what they wants to do with the items. If it's just print, then yes. Otherwise it's helpful to separate them.

Comment: Agreed - should be `new Array()` or `[]` though